# For loop closure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am hoping someone could help me out here in explaining to me what it is with my code that is not outputting what I am expecting. I have played with this and still can't figure out why the inside closure is not outputting anything.

```
for (var i = 1, len = $('.items').length + 1; i < len; i = i + 1) {
    var j = (function(i) {
        for (j = 0; j < i.length; j = j + 1) {
            $('nav').find('ul').addClass('tier' + j + '-items');
        }
    })(i);
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul class="items">
        <li class="item">Top level 1</li>
        <li class="item">Top level 1
            <ul>
                <li class="item">level 2</li>
                <li class="item">level 2</li>
                <li class="item">level 2
                    <ul>
                        <li class="item">level 3</li>
                        <li class="item">level 3</li>
                        <li class="item">level 3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item">Top level 1</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**EDIT**

I updated hoping this would work but no luck:

```
for (var i = 0, len = $('.items').length; i < len; i = i + 1) {
    (function(j) {
        for (var j = 0; j < i; j = j + 1) {
            $('nav').find('ul').addClass('tier' + j + '-items');
        }
    })(i);
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Sorry it was not clear what I was trying to do. Spencer was able to understand after a couple times and I appreciate the help. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Some HTML as well or maybe a Fiddle?

Comment: @Varun - I posted the HTML for what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: Alright, I've adjusted my answer based on your edit. I'm quite certain I understand what you are looking for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `i.length` is `undefined`. `i` is a number, it dose not have a `.length` property to it. That will make it so the inner loop never runs.

***Edit***:

I'm going to assume that what you want is to add the class `'tierN-items'` where `N` is the depth of the list as a tree. So your output would look like so:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="items tier1-items">
        <li class="item">Top level 1</li>
        <li class="item">Top level 1
            <ul class= "tier2-items">
                <li class="item">level 2</li>
                <li class="item">level 2</li>
                <li class="item">level 2
                    <ul class= "tier3-items">
                        <li class="item">level 3</li>
                        <li class="item">level 3</li>
                        <li class="item">level 3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item">Top level 1</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

For that what you seem to do isn't going to work because you are finding all `ul` in the `nav` regardless of the value of `j`. You are going to need a different approach. My solution would be modifying the selector as a string variable. Basically we find if the first `ul` exist, then we find if there is a `ul > li > ul`, then `ul > li > ul > li > ul`, and so on until there isn't such an element. In code that would look like so:

```
var level = 1;
var tierSearch = "nav > ul";
while($(tierSearch).length)
{
    $(tierSearch).addClass('tier' + level + '-items');
    level++;
    tierSearch += "> li > ul";
}
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/p9kvfdgq/)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you not only for showing me how the code should look, but also for the explanation that cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want

```js
$(function(){
  $('.items ul').each(function(k,v){
     $(this).addClass('tier' + k + '-items');
     $(this).prepend('<strong>Tier' + k + '-items</strong>'); // just to highlight
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="items">
    <ul >
        <li class="item">Top level 1</li>
        <li class="item">Top level 1
            <ul>
                <li class="item">level 2</li>
                <li class="item">level 2</li>
                <li class="item">level 2
                    <ul>
                        <li class="item">level 3</li>
                        <li class="item">level 3</li>
                        <li class="item">level 3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item">Top level 1</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if there is only a single `ul` per level, since it effectively is simply going through each found `ul` and adding `tierN` where `N = 0 .. n`. For example, if there where two `<ul>`'s on the last level it would count it as `tier[i]` and `tier[i+1]`.

Comment: right.. unless OP had specified otherwise that it could be